# How to assign the same controller method to handle two forms on two different views?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have two forms to contact in two different views.
One in the Home view and the other in Contact-us view.

I want to use the same controller method for both forms.

so that when I'm in the Home page and I submit the form from this view it must stay in the home page and when I am in the Contact-us page and I submit the form It stay in the page
Contact-us.

My problem is with the return method. how to solve it to not redirect to another view and I do not want to use two methods if it's possible.

```
@Controller
public class SendingController {
    @Autowired
    private EmailServiceImpl emailServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private MailValidator mailValidator;

    /* Send HTML mail (simple) */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMailSimple", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendSimpleMail(@Valid @ModelAttribute("mailForm") final Mail mailForm, BindingResult bindingResult)
            throws MessagingException {
        mailValidator.validate(mailForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "contact-us";
        }

        mailForm.setRecipientEmail("contact-test@gmail.com");
        this.emailServiceImpl.sendSimpleMail(mailForm);
        return "contact-us";

    }

}
```

contact-us.html

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/sendMailSimple}"
                            th:object="${mailForm}" role="form" id="contact-form"
                            method="post">
...
</form>
```

home.html

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post"
                                 action="#" th:action="@{/sendMailSimple}"
                                 th:object="${mailForm}" role="form">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to use one controller method to process two form and return to two different views?

Comment: @lucumt yes, I want to return two different views.

Comment: I added an answer,do not know if it matches your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have add a parameter to distinguish the two views,suppose the parameter is called *viewType*, then you can do it as follow:

contact-us.html

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/sendMailSimple}"
                            th:object="${mailForm}" role="form" id="contact-form"
                            method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="viewType" value="contact-us"/>
...
</form>
```

home.html

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post"
                                 action="#" th:action="@{/sendMailSimple}"
                                 th:object="${mailForm}" role="form">
     <input type="hidden" name="viewType" value="home"/>
    ...
</form>
```

So in controller we can get the *viewType* parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendMailSimple", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendSimpleMail(@Valid @ModelAttribute("mailForm") final Mail mailForm, String viewType,BindingResult bindingResult)
        throws MessagingException {
    mailValidator.validate(mailForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "contact-us";
    }

    mailForm.setRecipientEmail("contact-test@gmail.com");
    this.emailServiceImpl.sendSimpleMail(mailForm);

    if(viewType.equals("contact-us")){
     return "contact-us"
    }else{
      return "home";
    }
    //return viewType;can also return the viewType directly

}
```